# Can I make a cylinder emit light in three.js to make it look like a tube light?

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl, blender, light

I'm new to Blender and three.js and would like to know if there are any resources where I can learn how to effectively build a scene in Blender and then export it to three.js. In Blender you can make any mesh emit light, how can I do that in three.js? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try with the glow shaders like:

1) http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Glow.html

2) http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Simple-Glow.html

3) http://jeromeetienne.github.io/threex.geometricglow/examples/geometricglowmesh.html

git: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.geometricglow

misc: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Silhouette-Outlined_Diffuse

http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch21.html very good link.

Comment: Thanks! I could only find implementations of glow effects that don't really illuminate the surroundings like light sources do. Here is my demo http://serenitystudio.de/gooqx2.1/ does anyone have an idea how to accomplish a tube light? Or should I just use directional light to simulate the effect?

Comment: So this spoof you need to do which most game use they don't add real light to scene instead use lightmap concept check unity YouTube on lightmap you got to know what I mean